# Minesweeper: how many mines are near?

Tags: ruby, minesweeper

[Minesweeper in Ruby (from exercism.io)](http://exercism.io/exercises/ruby/minesweeper/readme):

> Write a program that adds the numbers to a minesweeper board.
>
> Minesweeper is a popular game where the user has to find the mines
>   using numeric hints that indicate how many mines are directly adjacent
>   (horizontally, vertically, diagonally) to a square.
>
> In this exercise you have to create some code that counts the number
>   of mines adjacent to a square.
>
> Transforms boards like this (where * indicates a mine):
>
> ```
> +-----+
> | * * |
> |  *  |
> |  *  |
> |     |
> +-----+
> ```
>
> into this:
>
> ```
> +-----+
> |1*3*1|
> |13*31|
> | 2*2 |
> | 111 |
> +-----+
> ```

As can be seen in the [provided test suite](http://exercism.io/exercises/ruby/minesweeper), a method `Board.transform` is required whose input and output are arrays of strings, representing the rows of the board. A `ValueError` must be raised in case of an invalid character or a non-border cell at the edge of the board.

My solution:

```
class ValueError < RuntimeError
end

class Position
  attr_reader :y, :x

  def initialize(y, x)
    @y, @x = y, x
  end

  def neighbors
    Position.each(y-1 .. y+1, x-1 .. x+1)
  end

  def self.each(ys, xs)
    return enum_for(__method__, ys, xs) unless block_given?

    ys.each do |y|
      xs.each do |x|
        yield Position.new(y, x)
      end
    end
  end

  def ==(other)
    to_a == other.to_a
  end

  alias eql? ==

  def hash
    to_a.hash
  end

  def to_a
    [y, x]
  end
end

class Cell
  BLANK_CELL_CHAR = ' '
  MINE_CELL_CHAR = '*'
  BORDER_CELL_REGEX = /\A[-+|]\z/

  def self.from_char(char)
    case char
    when BLANK_CELL_CHAR
      BlankCell.new
    when MINE_CELL_CHAR
      MineCell.new
    when BORDER_CELL_REGEX
      BorderCell.new(char)
    else
      raise ValueError, "Illegal character"
    end
  end

  def blank?
    false
  end

  def mine?
    false
  end

  def border?
    false
  end
end

class BlankCell < Cell
  attr_accessor :num_adjacent_mines

  def initialize(num_adjacent_mines = nil) # nil means unknown
    @num_adjacent_mines = num_adjacent_mines
  end

  def blank?
    true
  end

  def to_s
    if @num_adjacent_mines.nil? || @num_adjacent_mines == 0
      BLANK_CELL_CHAR
    else
      @num_adjacent_mines.to_s
    end
  end
end

class BorderCell < Cell
  def initialize(char)
    @char = char
  end

  def border?
    true
  end

  def to_s
    @char
  end
end

class MineCell < Cell
  def mine?
    true
  end

  def to_s
    MINE_CELL_CHAR
  end
end

class Board
  def self.transform(input)
    board = Board.new(input)
    board.transform!
    board.to_a
  end

  def initialize(input)
    @height = input.length
    @width = input.first.length

    raise ValueError, "All lines must be of the same length" if input.any? { |line| line.length != @width }

    @cells = Position.each(0...@height, 0...@width).map do |position|
      char = input[position.y][position.x]
      cell = Cell.from_char(char)
      raise ValueError, "Expected a border cell" if should_be_border?(position) && !cell.border?
      [position, cell]
    end.to_h
  end

  def transform!
    Position.each(0...@height, 0...@width).each do |position|
      tranform_at!(position)
    end
  end

  def to_a
    (0...@height).map do |y|
      (0...@width).map do |x|
        at(Position.new(y, x)).to_s
      end.join
    end
  end

  private

    def tranform_at!(position)
      cell = at(position)
      if cell.blank?
        cell.num_adjacent_mines = position.neighbors.count do |position|
          at(position).mine?
        end
      end
    end

    def at(position)
      @cells.fetch(position)
    end

    def should_be_border?(position)
      position.y == 0 || position.y == @height - 1 ||
        position.x == 0 || position.x == @width - 1
    end
end
```

What do you think?

Comment: Why is position a class?

Comment: @Nakilon Explain how I can solve this in a different way in your answer.

Comment: OOP is misused here. As I see Position here is conceptually just an Array with its own and 9 more coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using some kind of TDD all classes must be test-covered. Adding classes that are not mentioned in tests at least confusing, at most - leads to unnecessary complexity.

What is the difference between `Cell`, `MineCell`, `Bordercell` and `BlankCell`? They are storing input/output methods but must be responsible for business logic, I think. They are acting like higher level of `Position` abstraction. BTW, `Position.each` - good "trick".

Code is readable and easy to understand.

When I looked through once again, I noticed that this part can be improved:

```
def blank?
  false
end
def mine?
  false
end
def border?
  false
end
######
def blank?
  self.is_a?(BlankCell)
end
def mine?
  self.is_a?(MineCell)
end
def border?
  self.is_a?(BorderCell)
end
```

This methods definitions can be removed from `Cell`'s subclasses.

My way (written in "least resistance way" with tests):

```
class ValueError < RuntimeError; end

class Board

  def self.transform(input)
    validate(input)
    out = mark_field(substitute(input[1..-2]))
    to_s(out, input)
  end

private

  class << self
    def mark_field(field)
      field.each.with_index.with_object(field) do |(row, r_indx), obj|
        row.each.with_index do |cell, c_indx|
          increment_cells(r_indx, c_indx, obj) unless cell
        end
      end
    end

    def substitute(input)
      input.map do |line|
        line.gsub(/[^*\s]/, '').chars.map{ |ch| ch == '*' ? nil : 0 }
      end
    end

    def closest_cells(row, col, field)
      arr = (row-1..row+1).flat_map{ |r| [r].product([*(col-1..col+1)])}
      arr.reject{ |r, c| r < 0 || c < 0 || [r, c] == [row, col] || !(field[r] && field[r][c]) }
    end

    def increment_cells(row, col, arr)
      closest_cells(row, col, arr).each { |r, c| arr[r][c] += 1 }
    end

    def to_s(out, input)
      input[1..-2] = out.map do |line|
        "|#{line.map{ |c| c == 0 ? ' ' : c ? c : '*' }.join}|"
      end
      input
    end

    def validate(input)
      raise ValueError unless input.map(&:size).uniq.count == 1 &&
        input.reject{ |line| line.count('|') == 2 }.size == 2 &&
        !input.join.gsub!(/[^*\s\|\+\-]/, '')
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by asking: What is the problem really asking for?  As I see it, it's asking you to go through every cell on the grid and, if a cell is blank, fill it in with the number of surrounding bombs.  When viewed from that persepctive, a minimal solution is just a map over the grid, and a helper function to count bomb neighbors at a given position.

While taking an object-oriented approach might be appropriate as requirements grow, I think it is likely to lead to over-engineering for the problem at hand, and to obscure, rather than elucidate, the essence of the algorithm.  I can give advice on simplifying the OO solution if you like, but consider this alternative instead:

```
board = <<EOS
+-----+
| * * |
|  *  |
|  *  |
|     |
+-----+
EOS
.split("\n").map{|x| x.split('')}

def bomb_neighbors(i, j, arr)
  [-1,0,1].product([-1,0,1]).count {|k,l| arr[i+k][j+l] == '*' }
end

labeled_board = board.map.with_index do |row, i|
  row.map.with_index do |cell, j| 
    next cell unless cell == ' '
    bombs = bomb_neighbors(i, j, board)
    bombs == 0 ? ' ' : bombs
  end
end

puts labeled_board.map{|x| x.join('')}.join("\n")
```

You can probably appreciate the advantages at a glance, but to name a few:

- Shorter and clearer, with very little *incidental complexity*
- No need to create separate classes for the different "types" of cell.  For this problem, you care only if a cell is blank or non-blank.  Everything else returns itself.
- No need for case statements or regexes
- No need to think about the "border" in your solution -- it's not fundamentally part of the problem, so shouldn't play a role in the solution.